# -bash: syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error

I'm trying to build a todo task app. I've created the app `rails new`, specified the dependencies in the gemfile, ran `bundle install`, generated the model with `rails generate model Task title:string note:text completed:date`, applied changes with `rake db:migrate`.

The next command is to create a task with `Task.create`. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Task.create(title: 'First task',  note: 'This task was created inside the rails console')
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `title:'
```

I've also tried without the comma after 'First task' and with a space before the comma.

This syntax error shouldn't be happening. Any thoughts what the problem might be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be in Rails console before creating a task as such.

Enter `rails console` by executing the following in your bash prompt (from within your Rails application directory):

```
$ rails console
```

Then you can create the task from the console:

```
> Task.create(title: 'First task'  note: 'This task was created inside the rails console')
```

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked something soooo simple! Thanks Vee!